# Is there a way to read the inputstream for a specific amount of time?

Tags: java, stream, timeout, inputstream

I've a situation where a thread opens a telnet connection to a target m/c and reads the data from a program which spits out the all the data in its buffer. After all the data is flushed out, the target program prints a marker. My thread keeps looking for this marker to close the connection (successful read).

Some times, the target program does not print any marker, it keeps on dumping the data and my thread keeps on reading it (no marker is printed by the target program).

So i want to read the data only for a specific period of time (say 15 mins/configurable). Is there any way to do this at the java API level?

Comment: I hope I got your question right, but when you reading data using an InputStream invoking read() with a buffer of say 1024 bytes you can count the time you spent reading by taking the differnce  to  the start time, for every loop your method spent reading.

Comment: Yes this approach works but isn't this non optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another thread to close the connection after 15 mins.  Alternatively, you could check after each read if 15mins have passed and then simply stop reading and cleanup the connection, but this would only work if you're sure the remote server will continue to send data (if it doesn't the read will block indefinitely).

Comment: java has a buitl-in mechanism for timeouts on socket, no need to create a thread for this.

Comment: setSoTimeout sets the timeout on each call to `read`.  If the remote end is constantly outputting data this won't help.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

Comment: The timeout will only work if the thread is blocked on a read operation. It won't work if the thread reads data coming from the server endlessly (which seems to be the case of the OP)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no. Input streams don't provide timeout functinality.

However, in your specific case, that is, reading data from a socket, yes. What you need to do is [set the SO_TIMEOUT on your socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) to a non-zero value (the timeout you need in millisecs). Any read operations that block for the amount of time specified will throw a [`SocketTimeoutException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Watch out though, as even though your socket connection is still valid after this, continuing to read from it may bring unexpected result, as you've already half consumed your data. The easiest way to handle this is to close the connection but if you keep track of how much you've read already, you can choose to recover and continue reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Java Socket for your communication, you should have a look at the [setSoTimeout(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) method.

The read() operation on the socket will block only for the specified time. After that, if no information is received, a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` will be raised and if treated correctly, the execution will continue.

Answer (score 0):

If the server really dumps data forever, the client will never be blocked in a read operation. You might thus regularly check (between reads) if the current time minus the start time has exceeded your configurable delay, and stop reading if it has.

If the client can be blocked in a synchronous read, waiting for the server to output something, then you might use a [SocketChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html), and start a timer thread that interrupts the main reading thread, or shuts down its input, or closes the channel.